# Adding a new method to existing modular pattern object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, closures

I have the following module with two methods, `A()` and `B()`:

```
var Module = (function() {

    function A(){
      console.log("Module: A");
      B();
    };

    function B(){
       console.log("Module: B");
       Module.Utils.C(); /* Here is the problem */
    };

    return {
      A:A,
      B:B
    }

} ());
```

Say I want to add a new method `C()`...

```
function C(){
      console.log("C");
    };
```

...to the above module without touching it, i.e., I don't want to change the existing code of `Module` but to extend it to have new `C` property.

Comment: This is a good question but I'm confused by one part of it. From the commented bit of your code where you point out where your problem is, it looks like you actually want to extend a `Utils` property of `Module` which isn't defined in your code. So do you want to extend `Module` or an object called `Utils` which should belong to `Module`?

Comment: Another question: Should `Utils` or `C` be private or public? Should they be privileged (i.e., have access to private variables within your closure)?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do the following after the module definition:

```
Module.Utils = Module.Utils || {};
Module.Utils.C = function(){
  console.log("C");
};
```

The first line checks whether Module.Utils is defined already and defines it if it isn't. The next part then assigns the function C.

If you try to just do `Module.Utils.C = function(){ console.log("C"); };` then you would get an error about Module.Utils being undefined.

I've created a fiddle here showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/u5R4E/

Answer (score 0):

You can add methods to object dynamicaly:

```
Module.Utils.C = function(){
  console.log("C");
};
```

Comment: That is true as long as C does not want to access any variables or functions defined within the closure. And that is the main purpose of the module pattern, isn't it?